# Where to find my netbeans glassfish installation?

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I have installed one glassfish server manually and one is installed with netbeans IDE.
How I can know which one is installed with netbeans?

Answer (score 8):

The one installed by NetBeans should be automatically registered with NetBeans, so go to the Tools -> Servers menu and select the Glassfish server. It will tell you, roughly, where the server was installed (it will give you a location of the Domains folder, which is under the root installation).